# Count SalesOrder Items more elegantly in SuiteTalk

Tags: c#, netsuite, suitetalk

I'm working on creating the backend for a NetSuite-based application using SuiteTalk. I'm trying to count the total number of items in SalesOrders.

My issue is that, when performing a search operation to get all SalesOrders, the `Record[]` object returned loses precision when cast to a `SalesOrder[]` (using `Array.ConvertAll(...)` and manually). In my case, this means getting a Null Reference exception when trying to access the itemList field.

My eventual solution was as follows:

```cs
for (SearchResult searchResult = _service.search(salesOrderSearch); searchResult.pageIndex <= searchResult.totalPages; searchResult = _service.searchNext()) {

                if (searchResult.status.isSuccess) {

                    // Convert Record[] to SalesOrder[]. Note that direct conversion causes some fields to become Null 
                    SalesOrder[] salesOrdersNull = Array.ConvertAll(searchResult.recordList, item => (SalesOrder)item);

                    // To avoid the null issue, send a get request for each order by its internalId
                    foreach (SalesOrder salesOrderNull in salesOrdersNull) {
                        SalesOrder salesOrder = getSalesOrder(salesOrderNull.internalId);

                        // Increment the count by the total number of items
                        count += salesOrder.itemList.item.Length;
                    }
                } else {
                    string errorCodes = Helpers.generateErrorString(searchResult.status.statusDetail);
                    throw new SuiteTalkServiceException("count Sales Order Lines. Failed with error code(s) " + errorCodes);
                }
            }
```

However this calls a get request for every single Sales Order, meaning it takes an age and is very inelegant. Is there a more elegant solution I'm missing? Has anyone else had a similar issue or am I being dense?

The class definition for Record is:

```cs
public abstract partial class Record {

        private string[] nullFieldListField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("name", IsNullable=false)]
        public string[] nullFieldList {
            get {
                return this.nullFieldListField;
            }
            set {
                this.nullFieldListField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The class definition for SalesOrder is several thousand lines of code, but the [SchemaBrowser entry](http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/schema/record/salesorder.html) is fairly clear.

Comment: What do you mean loses precision? Why can't you map it? Can you please post the class definitions for both `SalesOrder` and `Record`?

Comment: I intended "In my case, this means getting a Null Reference exception when trying to access the itemList field." to explain what I meant by loses precision. For clarification, I mean that some fields become null. I have added class definition for Record and the SchemaBrowser entry for SalesOrder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612714/get-items-in-a-purchaseorder-using-suitetalk?rq=1).

Essentially, to prevent the `itemList` field from becoming `null`, you have to set the `searchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly` field to `false`. This now runs in 1/10th the time of my solution.